# getting values to populate a text instead of the span

Tags: javascript, html

I have pieced together a script that adds the values in text boxes and displays the sums in a span. I have tried a ton of things, but I can not get it to display the sums in a input textbox. Here is a fiddle that I have been working in .. 
http://jsfiddle.net/elevationprint/MaK2k/17/

Basically I want to change the spans to input text boxes. If anyone can take a look and let me know what I am missing, I would appreciate it!
The code is this

HTML

```
Red<br>
12x12<input class="qty12" value="" /><br/>
12x24<input class="qty24" value="" /><br>
<br>
Blue<br>
12x12<input class="qty12" value="" /><br/>
12x24<input class="qty24" value="" /><br>
<br><br>
Total = <span class="qty12lable"></span> x $.95<br>
Total = <span class="qty24lable"></span> x $1.40<br>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.qty12').keyup(function(){
   var qty12Sum=0;
    $('.qty12').each(function(){
        if (this.value != "")
           qty12Sum+=parseInt(this.value);

});
   // alert('foo');
    $(".qty12lable").text(qty12Sum);
    //console.log(amountSum);        });


$('.qty24').keyup(function(){
   var qty24Sum=0;
    $('.qty24').each(function(){
        if (this.value != "")
           qty24Sum+=parseInt(this.value);

});
   // alert('foo');
    $(".qty24lable").text(qty24Sum);
    //console.log(amountSum);    });
```

Comment: have you tried to replace `<span class="qty12lable"></span>` with `<input class="qty12lable" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the input fields like so:

```
Total = <input class="qty12lable" value=""> x $.95<br>
Total = <input class="qty24lable" value=""> x $1.40<br>

$("input.qty12lable").val(qty12Sum);
$("input.qty24lable").val(qty24Sum);
```

Comment: Thank you!! It was the .val
I kept trying .value

Answer (score 1):

To set the text (value) of a textbox you have to use `.val()` not `.text()`. Like this:

```js
$('.qty12').keyup(function() {
  var qty12Sum = 0;
  $('.qty12').each(function() {
    if (this.value != "")
      qty12Sum += parseInt(this.value);

  });
  
  
  $(".qty12lable").val(qty12Sum);
});


$('.qty24').keyup(function() {
  var qty24Sum = 0;
  $('.qty24').each(function() {
    if (this.value != "")
      qty24Sum += parseInt(this.value);

  });
  
  
  $(".qty24lable").val(qty24Sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Red
<br>12x12
<input class="qty12" value="" />
<br/>12x24
<input class="qty24" value="" />
<br>
<br>Blue
<br>12x12
<input class="qty12" value="" />
<br/>12x24
<input class="qty24" value="" />
<br>
<br>
<br>Total = <input class="qty12lable"/> x $.95
<br>Total = <input class="qty24lable"/> x $1.40
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet has some logic about how you can attach event listeners on input fields and how you can get their values. It's not perfect and has quite a few bugs from production level perspective but this will give a hint about how you can listen and manipulate DOM using Jquery. Which is what Jquery is all about.

```js
$( "input" )
  .change(function () {
   var prevVal = ($('#total').html() !== '') ? $('#total').html() : 0;
   if(parseInt($(this).val()) === NaN) {
     return;
   }
   $('#total').html(parseInt($(this).val()) + parseInt(prevVal));
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="1"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="2"></input><br>
<hr>
Total = <span id="total" class="qty12lable"></span> <br>
```